# How to delete P4 client saved on my local workspace in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, windows, eclipse-plugin, perforce, p4eclipse

I want to delete the client dpi-sigs which I created on my windows machine, I tried to remove the directory but nothing happened.

[image: Click here to check the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the command line this will do it:

```
p4 client -d dpi-sigs
```

Comment: Sam can you please check that Image, I just installed it, not using it on cmd

Comment: Information about your client is stored on the Perforce server. Removing the directory on your workstation is fine, but you have to issue a command to the Perforce server to tell it to remove your client information from its database. Your server administrator can help you with this.